# How do I add values to each level of a stacked area plot from a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm writing a report for nightly Automation runs, and want to provide a simple to understand accumulated graph of previous builds. I have a `Pandas Dataframe`, which looks like this:

```
               0006.39  0006.44  0006.50  0007.61  0008.66
Type  Status                                               
CTS   Pass          120     16.0    120.0     99.0     58.0
      Failed         96    200.0     96.0    117.0    158.0
      Didnt run       0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
SDK   Pass          166    108.0    117.0     96.0     74.0
      Failed        126     38.0     25.0     31.0     29.0
      Didnt run     103    249.0    268.0    283.0    307.0
Total Pass          286    124.0    237.0    195.0    132.0
      Failed        222    238.0    121.0    148.0    187.0
      Didnt run     103    249.0    268.0    283.0    307.0
```

and I use the following code to create the graph:

```
def create_graphs(sum_dt):
    for t in sum_types:
        plt.interactive(True)
        sum_dt.loc[t].T.plot(kind = 'area', stacked=True, title = t, color = ['green', 'red', 'grey'], grid = True).get_figure()
        plt.show(block=True)
```

I want to plot the value of each status, so it's clear for each build and each Status, what the value is. How do I do that?

Comment: And I'm sorry for the way the dataframe looks here, it's the first time I ask a question here and had no idea how to fix it :\

Comment: But what is the question? Does this work? or do you get errors?

Comment: The question is HOW do I add the values to the plot?